# Rails 4: Update table on ajax request from chrome extension

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4

On my webpage, I have a table of sports. When a user navigates to espn.com in a seperate tab, they have the ability via my chrome extension to highlight a sport and add it to their list of sports. When they add, this sends a POST request to my server to add the sport to the database.

Unfortunately, when the user then switches tabs again and looks at their sports table, the new sport is not in the table unless they refresh the page. How can I execute some JS to instruct my page to add a row with the newest sport when it is added to the database? I would prefer to do this via a js.erb file server side which appends a row to the sports table; however, when the js.erb is run, it appears to run it on espn.com rather than on my own webpage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either do polling with **setTimeout** or setup a **websocket** that can receive a push notification from your server.  Both of these methods will allow the tab, while it is not selected, to make an ajax call and update the content on the page.

Here's a simple way to do the polling method:

```
function poll_for_changes() {
  // Make your ajax call here
  $.get()
  // Everytime the polling routine finishes, have it register itself to run again...
  setTimeout(poll_for_changes, 5000);
}
// On page load start the polling routine
setTimeout(poll_for_changes, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. I wanted to avoid hitting the db often with a timeout and wanted to avoid the upfront time it would take to setup a websocket, but looks like there aren't any other options.

Comment: For websockets, especially for a lightweight solution, I'd recommend Faye.  You can run it via NodeJS or on Thin (Ruby) and it makes things pretty much as low impact as possible.  http://faye.jcoglan.com/

Comment: Great, I'll give it a look. Appreciate the recommendation.